# Series of questions on ring theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I have a few questions on rings. Some I can answer and some I am not really sure. I would appreciate your thoughts on the following questions:

> In which rings is the null-ideal (0) a prime ideal?

First of all $R\neq \{0\}$, else $(0)=\{0\}$ and it is not a prime ideal by definition.
Now (0) is a prime ideal iff xy=0 and x=0 or y=0. Therefore (0) is a prime ideal in every (non-trivial) integral domain.

> What are the consequences of $(a)=(b)$ of two principal ideals in a integral domain?

Since $(a)\subseteq (b)$ we have $b|a$ and $(a)\supseteq (b)$ we have $a|b$. Therefore $a=b$.
Is there more?

> What are the prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$. Which of them are maximal and which are prime?

The prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$ are of the form $p\mathbb{Z}$ where $p$ is prime.
Every prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$ is also a maximal ideal, since $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is a field.

> Is there a ring with just one maximal ideal, which is not a field?

Suppose $R$ is a field and $I\subsetneq R$ the only maximal ideal. Then is $R/I$ a field too.
Let $[0]\neq [r]\in R/I$, so $r\in R$. Since $R$ is a field, there is a $x\in R$ with xr=1, therefore $[xr]=[1]$ and $[xr-1]=[0]$. So $xr-1\in I$. But $x,r\in R-I$. Hence $1\in I$, but then $I=R$. Contradiction to the fact that $I$ is a maximal ideal.

There is no field with one maximal ideal. 
There should be no fields with maximal ideals!
Am I correct ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is admissible to post a series of questions under the stipulation that they are very highly coupled, so that they don't make sense in isolation. Yours is just literally a series of questions, none of them depending on each other. So in the future, you ought not to post such a list. You will simply have to post them separately.

Comment: I dont see a problem in asking four questions, which can get answered in a few sentences, maybe just one. And not taking the option of flooding the site with four seperate questions.

Comment: Dear @Cornman : the strategy has three obvious problems. 1) It can complicate answers: some people giving solutions may not be able to solve *all* parts. What do they do then? Post incomplete answers? Not answer at all?  I just happened to have responses for everything you asked, but it is sometimes not easy to do that. 2) It circumvents the builtin limitations on how many questions you can ask per day. This could be viewed as an attempt to cheat the guiderails that we all have to abide. 3) It hinders the searchability of the stackexchange, by making answers hard to find for these questions.

Comment: I don't want you to make a flood of questions either, but posting long lists of questions is not the solution. A couple of questions that are interrelated are fine, but asking questions that are barely related is not good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Therefore (0) is a primeideal in every (non-trivial) integral domain.

Yes. Also "prime ideal" is not a single word.

> Since $(a)\subseteq (b)$ we have $b|a$ and $(a)\supseteq (b)$ we have $a|b$. Therefore $a=b$.

Your conclusion is wrong. A counterexample is $a=2$ and $b=-2$ in $\mathbb Z$.  You'll have to reexamine your argument. If $a|b$ and $b|a$, you can say something very specific about the connection between the two.

> Is there a ring with just one maximal ideal, which is no field?

Yes. $\mathbb R[x]/(x^2)$ is an example.

> There should be no fields with maximal ideals! Am I correct?

No. In fields, the zero ideal is the one and only maximal ideal. Rings with identity always have maximal ideals.

Comment: What is the maximal ideal in $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2)$. When $[f]\in \mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2)$, then $\deg([f])\leq 1$. The only maximal ideal is then the set $\mathbb{R}$ itself? Hence $I=\{[f]\in\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2)| \deg([f])\in\{0,-\infty\}$, where $\deg(0)=-\infty$. Then $I\subsetneq\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2)$ because $[x]\notin I$ for example. And there can not be an other maximal ideal. What would be other ideals in $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2)$?

Comment: @Cornman $\mathbb R[x]/(x^2)$ has exactly three ideals: the two trivial ideals, and the ideal generated by $x$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you.